# Why isn't anything passed to the .UseStartup<Startup>() method in default webapi .Net Core application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Upon [creating a .Net Core webapi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio-code) application, the following code is created in Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace dotnet_testing
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

Why isn't anything passed to the .UseStartup() method?

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>();
```

From what I'm [understanding in the "WebHostBuilderExtensions.UseStartup Method" documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuilderextensions.usestartup?view=aspnetcore-2.1), you are supposed to pass an IWebHostBuilder:

```
UseStartup<TStartup>(IWebHostBuilder)
```

I'm not seeing a dependency injection in the "using" statements, so it doesn't seem to be injected.

Comment: `UseStartup` is an extension method, so although it *looks like* that first parameter needs to be passed in, it doesn't. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) for more information on extension methods (note the `this` keyword on the parameter).

Comment: @KirkLarkin  Got it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

if we take a closer look to the signature of the method

```
public static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder UseStartup<TStartup>
  (this Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder hostBuilder) where TStartup : class;
```

we will see that it is **An Extension Method**, hence it uses itself as parameter.

**Edit: Info About Extension Methods**

this keyword points itself. Lets say that we need to write Extension Method which dublicates string. then,

```
public static class StringExtensions {
    public static string DublicateString(this string myString) => $"{myString}{myString}";
}
```

then in order to use it

```
var str = "JohnDoe";
var result = str.DublicateString();
```

The compiler automatically translates `str.DublicateString()` into:

```
var str = "JohnDoe";
var result = StringExtensions.DublicateString(str);
```

Comment: Thanks... but I don't fully understand how it gets "itself" (the 'this') as a an argument.  I'm not passing anything in as an argument when I call it; I'm not passing 'this' or a reference to the object type.  Is there some default thing that says if you include "this" in a function's parameters, the self-reference is automatically injected?  (Like an optional parameter with a default of 'this')

Comment: check my answer. further documentation can be found on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

Comment: I read it, but didn't see anything refer to how the 'this' magically gets injected.

Comment: It is language specific feature.  What do you expect to see?

Comment: @DedicatedManagers the extension method is just syntactic sugar that makes a static method call look like an instance method call.  You can even call it in your code as a static method instead (but then you can't chain the method calls).  In this case, the static method syntax is `WebHostBuilderExtensions.UseStartup<Startup>(WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args));`.  In other words, the answer to "how does the 'this' magically gets injected?" is "by the compiler."  (And it's not optional.)